# need to put a figure above another figure in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

In beamer I created a slide like

[image]

using code

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{beaver} %{beetle}%{crane} 
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title[Madgraph Vs Phantom]{Introduction to Pile-Up}
\author[Ramkrishna Sharma]{Ramkrishna Sharma}
\institute[]{University of Delhi}
\date{August 24, 2014}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[slide number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{Mass of Two tagged Jet }
         \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=8cm]{Massesjj.pdf}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now, I need to put another figure on the figure displayed in the figure. and it should appear when I press enter.

Also I need to put an arrow to from figure to point a  point in the figure which is already there. As shown in figure below:[image]

The Black box should be replaced by another figure in next click.

Please suggest what should I do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Well, the first thing that you should do is to add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that):). This way people can see what your set-up is and what you have tried and they have something to work from. Doing this makes it much easier for people to help you -- and much more likely they they will. This said, you probably just need `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble and `\includegraphics{image}` in your beamer file, probably in a `tabular` environment to put them side by side.

Comment: I added what I did. But I need to put them one above the other not side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to draw an arrow it is probably easiest to put everything inside a `tikzpicture` environment.

Before I answer your question let me say that using

```
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=8cm]{Massesjj.pdf}
```

to include your image is probably a mistake. It is better to specify either the height that you want, or the width, but not both as this may skew the image. If you only specify the "important" dimension then the other one will be scaled, without changing the aspect ratio of the image.

In order to put the second image on top after you have displayed the first image you an use the pause command. The image is for the second slide:

[image]

...and here is how this was done:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}% this is necessary for drawing arrows
\usepackage{mwe}% you can omoit this one, it's just needed for the images
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Mass of Two tagged Jet }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=center}]
    \node(a) at (8,4){\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}};
    \pause
    \node(b) at (10,5){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}};
    \draw[red,thick,->](10,5)--(4,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now, I edited the question again. Sorry, This is first time I am posting so could not putted full information. But form next time I will remember these things. Thanks.

Comment: @ramkrishna I've updated my answer and put a `\pause` between the two images. Hopefully this is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. 

But I need to put height and width both in the \includegraphics otherwise my image is not filling the whole frame.